# How to resolve "property doesn't exists in type object" error in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my application there is a  parent component that contains a list of objects that represents different fruits. When a user selects a fruit, its data are passed to the child component which 
displays all the data as details.

```
        <app-details 
            [fruit]="selectedFruit"
        ></app-details>
```

Inside the details template:

```
<div class="fruit-details">
    <h1>{{fruit.name}}</h1>
    <h1>{{fruit.color}}</h1>
    <h1>{{fruit.description}}</h1>
</div>
```

'fruit' property is set to type object in details component.
`@Input()fruit: Object;`

An error occurs stating something like `Property 'description' does not exist on type 'Object'`. Not setting "fruit" property to datatype of "Object" solves the issues. But How can I solve this issue without removing the data type.

Comment: Object is not the right type for fruit. `fruit: { [key: string]: any }` would work better, and if you could create your own Fruit interface, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an interface for `Fruit` and then use that as your type:

```
interface Fruit { 
    name: string;
    color: string;
    description: string;
}

@Input()fruit: Fruit;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using @Input()fruit: string, stringify your selectedFruit

```
JSON.stringify(selectedFruit)
```

in details component parse it :

```
let parseFruit = JSON.parse(this.fruit); 
console.log(parseFruit);
```

Answer (score 0):

to my best knowledge and after hours of searching, all you need to do is to Declare any variable  that you intend to use in your HTML at the class level of your component (where the export class definition at  your type script)

I hope to hear it solved the  problem  to anyone
Beni Dayan.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).